# How to get year in sql function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a following function to create a unique number by SQL server.

```
USE [icelandtaxitours_development]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ufnInvoiceNumber]    Script Date: 10.2.2014 22:53:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnInvoiceNumber](
    @Value int
) 
RETURNS varchar(6) 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(8);

    SET @ReturnValue = CONVERT(varchar(8), @Value);
    SET @ReturnValue = Year(Getdate()) + '-' + REPLICATE('0', 8 - DATALENGTH(@ReturnValue)) + @ReturnValue;

    RETURN (@ReturnValue);
END;
```

and when i call it in formula i do following:

```
(isnull([dbo].[ufnInvoiceNumber]([InvoiceID]),''))
```

...now I simply get a number "2015" .. what I want is a number "2014-00000001" as an invoice number.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: This actually works?  You don't get a type error on this part of the code:  `Year(Getdate()) + '-'`?

Comment: You're returning a maximum of only 6 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may be getting confused on whether you want numeric addition or string concatenation.  To be safe you could cast the year to a string:

```
SET @ReturnValue = CONVERT(CHAR(4),Year(Getdate()))
                   + '-' 
                   + REPLICATE('0', 8 - DATALENGTH(@ReturnValue)) + @ReturnValue;
```

Plus you need to increase the length of your return type:

```
RETURNS varchar(13)
```

Comment: Hi
I get the year now....but not the rest :/ 
My invoice number is now (after alteration) 2014-0 when it should be 2014-00000001

Comment: See the note on your return type - you're only returning 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you want is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnInvoiceNumber](
    @Value int
) 
RETURNS varchar(255) 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(255);

    SET @ReturnValue = CONVERT(varchar(8), @Value);
    SET @ReturnValue = cast(Year(Getdate()) as varchar(255)) + '-' + REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@ReturnValue)) + @ReturnValue;

    RETURN (@ReturnValue);
END;
```

The most important part is changing the return type to a `varchar()` that is big enough to hold the value that you want and changing the corresponding type for `@ReturnValue` in the code.  I also added an explicit cast for the year to avoid data errors and replace `datalength()` with `len()` because you are working with a simple character string.

Actually I would prefer to write the body as:

```
    SET @ReturnValue = (cast(Year(Getdate() as varchar(255)) + '-' +
                        LEFT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + cast(@value as varchar(8)), 8
                       );    
    RETURN (@ReturnValue);
```

Comment: Correct closing parentheses near getdate().